# CSS flexbox layout not working in safari

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, angular-material

Trying to achieve a flexbox layout using angular material where the navigation and footer have a fixed height, the content will be scrollable (using md-content) and the footer should appear after the scrollable content.  My solution works fine in chrome and firefox, but not in safari.  In safari, the Footer appears at the bottom of the viewport, overlapping the scrollable content.  Any way to achieve the same effect in all browsers?

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.10.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  </head>

  <body layout='column'>

    <div id='nav'>
      Nav
    </div>

    <md-content flex layout='column'>

      <div id='content' flex>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>

      <div id='footer'>
        Footer
      </div>

    </md-content>

  </body>

</html>
```

css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#nav{
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 65px;
  flex: 0 0 65px;
}

#content{
  background-color: blue;
}

#footer{
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 115px;
  flex: 0 0 115px;
}
```

plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ibi6v1LTy9dLducHuMdM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#content {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Your hierarchy is a little wonky, and it appears that Safari is struggling with that.

By moving the footer to be a sibling of the `#nav` and `md-content`elements, and removing the redundant flex displays, you can get the layout you're looking for.

New HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
      Nav
    </div>
<md-content layout="column">
  <div id="content">
    <p>...</p>
    ...
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</md-content>
<div id="footer">
  Footer
</div>
```

New CSS:

```
#content{
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1;
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

## <kbd>[Plunkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/fOlEP16tCkfZlwFlnCju?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: I need a sticky footer, not fixed. Thanks though

Comment: Sticky in the sense it follows the content?  So put it in the content and avoid the flex on the element altogether.  You don't need a flex display for that. Here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/M4KeFHNTyumbd5H6s7bg?p=preview

Comment: Yes like that, but when the content doesn't scroll, the footer should appear at the bottom of the view height. Like this: [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/).  I can't get it to work from within the md-content.